# Why is Filezilla not displaying on any of my monitors?

Tags: windows, filezilla

Filezilla was working on my computer until just a couple hours ago, and now when I try to open it it says that it is opened in the task manager and you can see the icon in the taskbar but clicking on it doesn't bring up filezilla. I also tried clicking on the filezilla icon and using the windows button + arrow key shortcut to  move the program to a specific part of the window but that did nothing either. After that I tried restarting my computer, I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling filezilla and neither of those did anything (though I had an odd bug where filezilla didn't delete any of it's files when I told it to uninstall the second time and I had to delete most of those files by hand). I have tried googling my issue but haven't found anything that would help. Do y'all have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filezilla does not delete the folder in AppData when it's uninstalled.
You could try to either delete or rename the folder Filezilla which can be found in "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming".